# How to access marks list outside test script

Tags: python, pytest

I have a mark, let say, `specific_case = pytest.mark.skipif(<CONDITION>)` which I need to apply to some test-cases. I want property `value` to return different value in case mark applied. This is my simplified code:

**module.py**:

```
import pytest

class A():
    @property
    def value(self):
        _marks = pytest.mark._markers # current code to get applied marks list
        if 'specific_case' in _marks:
            return 1
        else:
            return 2
```

**test_1.py**:

```
import pytest
from module import A

pytestmark = [pytest.mark.test_id.TC_1, pytest.mark.specific_case]

def test_1():
    a = A()
    assert a.value == 1
```

But that doesn't work as `pytest.mark._markers` returns `set(['TC_1', 'skipif'])` but not exact `pytestmark` list (I expect `set(['TC_1', 'specific_case'])` or at least `pytestmark` as it is - `[pytest.mark.test_id.TC_1, pytest.mark.specific_case]`).

So is there any way I can access exact `pytestmark` list outside test function?

P.S. I also found some tips of how to get mark list using fixtures, but I should stick to current implementation of `module.py` and `test_1.py`, so cannot use fixture.

Also there are many other marks with skip conditions (`specific_case_2 = pytest.mark.skipif(<CONDITION_2>)`, `specific_case_3 = pytest.mark.skipif(<CONDITION_3>)`,...), so I cannot use just `if 'skipif' in _marks` solution

Answer (score 1):

Since your `module.py` accesses `pytest` marks, then it is safe to assume that it is part of the test code.

With that said, in case you are you open to changing the class property `A.value` into a `pytest` fixture, then this alternative solution might work fine for you. Otherwise, this wouldn't suffice.

### Alternative Solution

Instead of using `pytest.mark._markers` to retrieve the marks list, use [request.keywords](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html?highlight=request%20keywords#pytest.FixtureRequest.keywords).

> class FixtureRequest
>
> keywords
>
> - Keywords/markers dictionary for the underlying node.

```
import pytest


# Data

class A():
    @property
    def value(self):
        _marks = pytest.mark._markers  # Current code to get applied marks list
        print("Using class property A.value:", list(_marks))
        if 'specific_case' in _marks:
            return 1
        else:
            return 2


@pytest.fixture
def a_value(request):  # This fixture can be in conftest.py so all test files can see it. Or use pytest_plugins to include the file containing this.
    _marks = request.keywords  # Alternative style of getting applied marks list
    print("Using pytest fixture a_value:", list(_marks))
    if 'specific_case' in _marks:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2


# Tests

pytestmark = [pytest.mark.test_id, pytest.mark.specific_case]

def test_first():
    a = A()
    assert a.value != 1  # 'specific_case' was not recognized as a marker


def test_second(a_value):
    assert a_value == 1  # 'specific_case' was recognized as a marker
```

Output:

```
pytest -q -rP --disable-pytest-warnings
..                                                                                                                                                                                                  [100%]
================================================================================================= PASSES ==================================================================================================
_______________________________________________________________________________________________ test_first ________________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Using class property A.value: ['parametrize', 'skipif', 'skip', 'trylast', 'filterwarnings', 'tryfirst', 'usefixtures', 'xfail']
_______________________________________________________________________________________________ test_second _______________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout setup ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Using pytest fixture a_value: ['specific_case', '2', 'test_1.py', 'test_second', 'test_id']
2 passed, 2 warnings in 0.01s
```